# And Conditions in Where IN Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have Query Like

```
select * from prop_unit_details where property_id in (7474218,9238369,2634062,993257,8418768,4189003)
```

But I wanted add **AND condition**  to this query Like

```
select * from prop_unit_details where property_id in (7474218,9238369,2634062,993257,8418768,4189003) and  bhk ='1BHK' and  budget > 500000
```

But Its not working how I can do that.

Comment: Please show the error message. “It is not working" is too generic.

Comment: I get Empty result set @Renzo

Comment: Add some sample data

Comment: So it works correctly and there are no data retrieved, since no row match the condition. Try with a simpler condition, for instance only with `select * from prop_unit_details  where bhk ='1BHK' and  budget > 500000` and see if the result contains rows with some `property_id` of those specified.

Comment: Data is Already There @SaurabhPandey

Comment: As said by @Renzo Please check the condition one by one. may be you don't have enough data with these condition into your database. First check the max budget of plots whose ids are listed above.

Comment: @Shankar Just check whether you table has records which satisfies all the 3 conditions.

Comment: Show at-least one sample record which satisfies the condition.

Comment: Thanks  i was wrong ..Solved My Problem

Comment: @Shankar Sounds like it wasn't a programming issue in that case. If that is correct the question can be deleted.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with everyone else's recommendations.  If, for some reason they do not work, the issue may be the string fields need `trim(bhk)` or converting to comparable data types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just select those two columns (bhk and budget in the first query that you have mentioned) that u have used in the 'and' condition and check whether the bhk column contains 1 BHK value and max value of budget is greater than 500000.

Eg:

```
SELECT bhk, budget 
FROM prop_unit_details 
WHERE property_id IN (7474218, 9238369, 2634062, 993257, 8418768, 4189003)
```